# Making list of files from folder and adding additional text via powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make list of kb in folder and add to results some additional text. Im trying like that, but its not like I want:

```
    $nazwa = Get-ChildItem -file "c:\2012 standart\" | select name 

     for($a=1 ; $a -le $nazwa.Length; $a++)
     {
      "start"
     "$nazwa[$a]"+"addiotional text"
     "stop"
      }
```

I would like results like that:

```
start

file1 additional text
file2 additional text
file3 additional text

stop
```

Where is the problem? Will be great grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
write-host "start"
$nazwa=Get-ChildItem -file "c:\temp\" |  select-object name 

foreach ($i in $nazwa  )
{
    write-host $i.name "addiotional text"
}
write-host "end"
```

Comment: @Czajnik: Please accept János' answer, if it helped you.

Comment: @János  How to redirect this output to file? I try .\generator.ps1 > list.txt, file is created but without outputs (empty), any idea?

Comment: $FileToWrite="C:\temp\test.txt"
"start" > $FileToWrite

$nazwa=Get-ChildItem -file "c:\temp\" |  select-object name 
 
foreach ($i in $nazwa  )
{
   $text=$i.name + "addiotional text" 
   $text>> $FileToWrite
}

"end" >> $FileToWrite